# Android service denied location permisions

Tags: android

So I am trying to get the current Location in a service which is being called by BroadcastReceiver. When I check to see if location permissions are given in the service it always fails. I am trying to get the current GPS location only.

Here is the BroadcastReceiver

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    private static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AlarmService.class));
    }

    /**
     * Cancels the alarm.
     * @param context
     */
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Service

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = AlarmService.class.getSimpleName();

    public AlarmService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<Trip> trips = realm.where(Trip.class).findAll();
        for (Trip trip : trips) {
            if (active(trip)) {
                getStamp(trip);
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void getStamp(Trip trip) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Getting Stamp");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Location found");
        //get and store current location using GPS only
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    }


    public boolean active(Trip trip){
        Date now = new Date();
        if(now.compareTo(trip.getStart()) > 0 && now.compareTo(trip.getEnd()) < 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and Here is my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapplication.app.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationSingleton"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".StartTravelActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TripsViewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TripDetailActivity" />

        <receiver android:name=".alarms.AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".alarms.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".alarms.AlarmReceiver" />

        <service
            android:name=".alarms.AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You call `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` to see if the permission is granted or not but you don't ask for that permission if it is not granted :-( take a look http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request

Comment: This task is run in the background. I thought it didn't have access to the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, in that case check for the required permissions, if you don't have them show a notification that the user has to grant them. if the user clicks on the notification open a activity (maybe without ui) and ask for the permissions

Comment: I'm requesting the permission in the manifest. Is there any reason that the app still doesn't have the permission?

Comment: It depends on your device. older android version are using the manifest but on newer android version you have to ask for the permission _Depending on the platform version, the user grants the permission either when they install the app (on Android 5.1 and lower) or while running the app (on Android 6.0 and higher)._ http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion  ?If it is 23 then requesting the permission in manifest will not be granted the user have to grant it at run time.http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/permissions/requesting.html